# Query for differentiate the records in stock,salesorder,dropout

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table lot and lot_transactions

**lot**

```
lotID       |   salesorderdocline   |         
-------------------------------------------------
72266414    |   15          |    
72266415    |   0           |    
72266416    |   0           |
```

**lot_transactions**

```
lotID       |   salesorderdocline   |   trstypeid   |   trsdate  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
72266414    |   0           |   400     |       19-05-2016   
72266414    |   11          |   1104    |       20-05-2016  
72266414    |   11          |   132     |       24-05-2016  
72266414    |   0           |   133     |       25-05-2016  
72266414    |   15          |   1104    |       30-05-2016  
72266415    |   0           |   400     |       04-02-2016  
72266416    |   0           |   400     |       03-02-2016  
72266416    |   10          |   1104    |       05-02-2016  
72266416    |   10          |   400     |       06-02-2016  
72266416    |   10          |   132     |       08-02-2016  
72266416    |   0           |   133     |       09-02-2016
```

**Output**

```
lotid       |   Stockstatus  
---------------------------------------- 
72266414    |   Salesorder  
72266415    |   Instock  
72266416    |   Dropout
```

**criteria for getting salesorder,Instock and Dropout**
72266414 is in salesorder because if we check the salesorderdocline it has changed from 0 - 11 -0 - 15
72266415 is in Instock because salesorderdocline is 0
72266416 is in Dropout because salesorderdocline has changes from 0-10-0.

if the salesorderdocline =0 it is stock.
if greater than 0 than in salesorder
**lot_transactions** is the table where we can see all the transactions for a particular lot
**lot** is the table where it will only show the current status

And I am using MSSQL database

Comment: what are the rules for `Salesorder` , `Instock` or `Dropout` ? Your description is not that clear

Comment: @Squirrel if the salesorderdocline is changing from 0 - 11 -0 - 15 than its a **salesorder**  
if the salesorderdocline is only 0 and there is no other transactions than it is **Instock**  
if the salesorderdocline is changing from 0-10-0 than it is **dropout**

Comment: So if the final qty is `> 0` than it is `SalesOrder` , if final qty is 0, it is `dropout` ? if final qty is 0 and it is the only transaction than it is `instock`?

Comment: @Squirrel for dropout if the final qty has changed to 0 from someother salesorderdocline lets say 11 or 12 or 13 only than its a drop out. rest other what you saying is correct

Comment: So the rules is it based on `final qty` or the transitional from one figure to another matters ?

Comment: @Squirrel from your query, salesorder data is coming absolutely perfect but if the lot is in stock it is showing in dropout

Comment: @Squirrel if under lot_transaction table if the salesorderdocline = 0 for either 1 transaction or 100 transaction it should be in stock only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT l.lotID,
       Stockstatus = case when l.salesorderdocline > 0
                          then 'SalesOrder'
                          when l.salesorderdocline = 0
                          and  not exists 
                               (
                                   select *
                                   from   lot_transactions x
                                   where  x.lotID = l.lotID
                                   and    x.salesorderdocline > 0
                               )
                          then 'Instock'
                          else 'Dropout'
                          end
FROM   lot l
```

Comment: if under lot_transaction table if the salesorderdocline = 0 for either 1 transaction or 100 transaction it should be in stock only and above query shows only salesorder and dropout. lot is showng in dropout eventough it is in stock

Comment: @RedDevil so what is your rule for `InStock` or `Dropout` ? How to differenciate it ?

Comment: so if the lot has never changed to salesorderdocline > 0 than it is in stock. But if it has changed from 0 to greater than 0 and than again 0 than it is dropout

Comment: so if there is only one line in lot_transaction then it is instock else dropout. Correct ?

Comment: no it can have multiple lines as well but salesorderdocline=0 throughout the transactions than it is in stock

Comment: so how to determine ? what is the rule ? (updated the query). If it is still not what you want, please do state the rules clearly

Comment: I have checked your updated query and so far so good its working absolutely fine. It is showing what I wanted.